# Regex matching double quotes enclosed values

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, lucene, pcre

According to the example in [this ElasticSearch documentation page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html#analysis-pattern-tokenizer) the following pattern matches values enclosed in double quotes:

```
"((?:\\"|[^"]|\\")*)"
```

Still I don't get the use of the second `\\"`, which seems redundant. Any light?

Comment: From what I see/comprehend, the entire alternation may not be necessary.  +1 anyway to your question.

Comment: I think maybe it's matching pairs of escaped quotes with anything non-quote in between, any number of times, until we hit a quote.

Comment: that's right. The question is: what is the rationale behind putting the escaped quote (`\\"`) twice in the OR?

Comment: Good point.  Seems redundant to me too; certainly it makes no difference whether it's there or not in their example

Comment: I'm reasonably sure it doesn't serve any purpose being there, but I wouldn't call it redundant, exactly. Note that, "((?:\\"|[^"])*)" works, but "((?:[^"]|\\")*)" doesn't. I'd guess they tried the second one first, and had to puzzle out [why it didn't work](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).